# Create a railing around a circle?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm doing a lighthouse in Blender and am trying to create a railing. 
Here's what I'm starting with:

[image]

It's on the "walking deck" I wanna build it. I tried one solution with subdividing edges and so on so it got to something like this (to start with).
[image]

The issue is, alot of work for doing the same thing over and over again, and also if you look at the bottom of the poles, the subdivision modifier does not make it look good anymore.

So looking for tips on how someone would do this a more correct way?

**UPDATE**
After trying the array around empty, this is what I ended up with:
[image]
As you can see it's mostly good, but the issue now is the clipping, like the rail clips in to the next pipe, and the pipe clips through the walking deck, don't even know if it's an issue? but the Subsurface doesn't look as it should because of it. Any tips?

**UPDATE 2**
Manage to fix it with the merge function to the other pipe.
But how do I merge the pipes with the deck to avoid clipping?

Comment: do you absolutely need to make it with one unique mesh? It would simplify if you made a second object, and you could use an Array modifier around an axis to make it turn around

Comment: Welcome, Cisco. Make a google search: Blender array around an empty.

Comment: @moonboots Okey, I'm not sure actually how it acts when making it a second object when exporting it to like X-Plane scenery and such. Maybe you know?

Comment: @LeoNas I tried this out, updated the post. Please see if you can help me with this also. :)